# Any restrictions on drift vector in Fokker-Planck equation?

Tags: friction, phase-space, diffusion, stochastic-processes

The most general Fokker-Planck equation for a probability density $f$ over phase space is

$$\partial_t f = -\partial_i(u^i f) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_i \partial_j (D^{ij} f)$$

where $u^i$ is the drift vector field on phase space, $D^{ij}$ is the diffusion matrix field, and the repeated indices $i,j=1,\ldots,2d$ are summed over the $2d$ phase-space directions.

To generically preserve the positivity property of $f$, we must have that $D^{ij}$ is positive semidefinite.  **Are there any constraints on the drift vector $u^i$ besides, perhaps, that it be sufficiently smooth?**

The drift vector can be decomposed as $u^i = \epsilon^{ij}\partial_j H + g^i + \partial_j D^{ij}/2$ where $\epsilon^{ij}$ is the symplectic form, $H$ is a Hamiltonian (scalar function on phase space), $g^i$ is the friction vector, and $\partial_j D^{ij}/2$ is the spurious drift.  $\epsilon^{ij}\partial_j H$ and $\partial_j D^{ij}/2$ are constrained, but is the friction vector $g^i$ arbitrary?